# Difference between Signum and Sine

Tags: calculus, geometry

What is the difference between signum(t) and sine(t) in terms of angles i-e; at which angles signum is zero and 1?

What is the Eular representation of signum(t)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signum functions is discontinuous at $x = 0$, while the sine function is continuous everywhere. However, in the complex plane, $$signum(z) = e^{iArgz}$$